# Mongodb. Get docs whose array field contains only words from query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Is it possible in mongodb to find documents in which all the words in the field are contained in the query and not vice versa?

**pseudo query:**

```
{title: 
    {$in: ["the", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumps", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog"]}
}
```

**docs:**

```
{'title': ["brown", "fox"}    #true
{'title': ["lazy", "dog"]}    #true
{'title': ["lazy", "dog", "sleep"]}    #false 'sleep' not in query
{'title': ["brown", "dog"]}    #true
{'title': ["jumps", "quick"]}    #true
{'title': ["smile", "fox"]}    #false 'smile' not in query
```

Comment: The default behavior is `any` that means that if there's at least 1 match in the query, it will return a true. You need to change it to `all` so that it is required for `all` elements to return true. I'm not proficient in MongoDB to help you with the query, but just pointing what needs to be changed for it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB aggregation offers more operations than standard `.find` method.

> Takes two or more arrays and returns an array that contains the elements that appear in every input array.
>   https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/#exp._S_setIntersection

Once we get intersection, we compare array size (I assume your arrays cannot have duplicate values)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          {
            $size: "$title"
          },
          {
            $size: {
              $setIntersection: [
                "$title",
                [
                  "the",
                  "quick",
                  "brown",
                  "fox",
                  "jumps",
                  "over",
                  "the",
                  "lazy",
                  "dog"
                ]
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NcjwTKmsqjz)